# Как в ruby создавать txt файл с переменной в названии?

Tags: ruby

**Вопрос в заголовке. Прилагаю код.**

*Задача от программы:* создать txt файл с определённым номером, каждый раз повышая этот номер на одну единицу. Это вообще можно реализовать в Руби?

```
loop do
id = 0
f = File.open('#{id}.txt', 'a')
id += 1
f.close
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Отвечу не напрямую, небольшим примером кода, который вы можете сами запустить в `irb`:

```
id = 42
'#{id}' # => "\#{id}"
"#{id}" # => "42"
```

В разнице между двумя последними строчками кода и состоит ваша проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Может вот так:

```
id = 0
loop do
f = File.open("#{id}.txt", 'a')
id += 1
f.close
end
```